# How to export a function in fish shell

Tags: shell, export, fish, dotfiles

I'm porting some of my script from `bash` to `fish` shell, and fail to get access to my utilities functions.

#### Bash

Here is how I do it in bash, first declare my methods in `"$HOME/.my-posixrc"`:

```
function configure_date_utilities() {
    function today() {
        to-lower "$(date '+%Y-%b-%d')"
    }
    function today-num() {
        to-lower "$(date '+%Y-%m-%d')"
    }
    function now() {
        to-lower "$(date '+%Y-%b-%d-%H:%M')"
    }
}
```

Then source this file :

```
source "$HOME/.my-posixrc"
```

So I can do:

```
$ today
```

> 2015-dec-13

#### Fish

```
function configure_date_utilities
    function today
        to-lower (date '+%Y-%b-%d')
    end
    function today-num
        to-lower (date '+%Y-%m-%d')
    end
    function now
        to-lower (date '+%Y-%b-%d-%H:%M')
    end
end
```

Then source this file in `~/.config/fish/config.fish`:

```
source "$HOME/.my-posixrc"
```

But the **methods aren't found**:

```
$ today
```

> The program 'today' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
>   sudo apt-get install mhc-utils

#### Question

How do I "export" my function so I can access them in my prompt?

P.S.: my [dotfiles are available on github](https://github.com/edouard-lopez/dotfiles/blob/df58af7a720d659439fc1e447d9f87baaa9be5b2/.my-fishrc#L45).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drop the outer function or call it in the file.

In fish, all functions are global, but your inner functions won't be defined because their definition is never run.

So either:

```
function configure_date_utilities
    function today
        to-lower (date '+%Y-%b-%d')
    end
    function today-num
        to-lower (date '+%Y-%m-%d')
    end
    function now
        to-lower (date '+%Y-%b-%d-%H:%M')
    end
end
configure_date_utilities
```

or

```
function today
    to-lower (date '+%Y-%b-%d')
end
function today-num
    to-lower (date '+%Y-%m-%d')
end
function now
    to-lower (date '+%Y-%b-%d-%H:%M')
end
```

Comment: I was loading the wrong version of my `~/.config/fish/config.fish`